# JavaScript get php array and post key + vaule to body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to coding and i have no idea why this is not working
please explain so i can learn, Thank You.
**EDIT:** Moving PHP to top is still not printing any thing.

```
        <?php
           //create array
            $someArray = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
            //encode array
            $someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
            //pritn array
        ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var array = "<?PHP echo $someJSON?>";
                var arrayDecode = jQuery.parseJSON(array);
                $.each(arrayDecode, function(key, value){
                    $('body').append(key + value + "<br><br>");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You initialize the array after you print it, so it won't print any values

Comment: The PHP doesn't need to be in the body, you can move it to the very top.

Comment: JiFus : Use ready() to make a function available after the document is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try This.
You Need to Declare PHP Variable Before use in JS Script.
Otherwise the variable doesn't have any value and it will return error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <?php
   //create array
   $someArray = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
   //encode array
   $someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
   ?>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var array = '<?php echo $someJSON; ?>';
     arrayDecode = jQuery.parseJSON(array);
     $.each(arrayDecode, function(key, value){
       $('body').append(key + value + "<br><br>");
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That PHP & jQuery will load but the code should not execute untill the document fully loads right? I mean $.ready(); waiting untill it's done loading?